# How to validate Checkbox in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

So what i want is to validate my **Checkbox** in my form and check if it's checked so i should save it as 1 in my database else as 0, like this :

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'publication',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',

            'options' => array(
                    'checked_value' => 1,
                    'unchecked_value' => 0,
            ),
    ));
```

But when i tried i got Null in my database !!, for more details i will write some of my codes,

**This is my view :**

```
    <label>Publication:</label>
    <?php
         echo $this->formInput($form->get('publication'));
    ?>
```

**And this is my Entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="publication", type="boolean")
 */
protected  $publication;

/**
 * Set publication
 *
 * @param boolean $publication
 * @return Article
 */
public function setPublication($publication)
{
    $this->publication = $publication;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get publication
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getPublication()
{
    return $this->publication;
}

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
   $this->publication  = (isset($data['publication']))  ? $data['publication']  : null;
}

 public function getInputFilter()
  {
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'publication',
                'required' => false,
        ));
```

So please if someone has any solution i will be so appreciative :)

Comment: Add a bool filter to your checkbox element and you're done. $form->getData() will contain true/false and all ORM/TableGateway will translate that to 1/0 respectively.

Comment: yes i try to find it but i didn't found anything helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a checkbox is not ticked, it is not included in the post. In your exchangeArray, you are setting it null in this case.

Comment: thanks @dualmon you're right i didn't pay attention to that :(, i change it to : $this->publication  = (isset($data['publication']))  ? true  : false;